# SMART status: failure imminent - file system unknown and inaccessible

Tags: hard-drive, backup, smart

I am currently trying to back up data from a hard drive which is about to fail, according to SMART. So I hooked the disk up to my SATA USB adapter and sure enough windows wouldn't recognize the device, so I booted up ubuntu.
smartctl says

`Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.`

So that's what I'm trying to do, but unfortunately gparted as well as the unity disk utility show me an unknown file system and the data is inaccessible.
Any ideas?

e: this is pretty important for me - might there be a stackexchange page that can help me better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to access the data after

- putting the drive back in the pc it came from,
- booting said pc up,
- agreeing to the security warning,
- starting windows,
- doing a clean shutdown,
- taking the disk back out and connecting it via usb to my pc.

All data was accessible and as far as I could see nothing was lost.
Since I did not make any image of the disk to work with it instead of working with the actual drive that's purely luck, if you are having the same problem, please attempt using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/565893/157486) method posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the raw contents of the whole disk into a file on an intact disk:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/some/intact/disk/MyFailingDisk.img
```

If your failing disk is not /dev/sda then adjust the command accordingly.

This allows you analyse the disk and rescue data later on in a safe manner.
If you do data rescue on the failing disk, you are risking the disk getting worse on each attempt.

How to rescue data is a topic for a separate question.